# Js code to play a video until it reaches a certain time

Tags: javascript, html, video

I was working on some code to play a video until it reaches a certain time. When it reaches that time it pauses the video for a minute. After the minute it resumes. For me the code doesn’t work:

```
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('#toggle');
const video = document.querySelector('#myVideo');
toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', toggleDarkMode);
function toggleDarkMode() {
  if (toggleSwitch.checked) {
    document.body.classList.add('dark-mode');
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('dark-mode');
  }
}
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
  const currentTime = video.currentTime;
  const hours = new Date().getHours();
  const minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
  if (hours === 08 && minutes === 15 && currentTime >= 495 && currentTime < 496) {
    video.pause();
    setTimeout(function() {
      video.play();
    }, 60000);
  }
});
```

**For a better version follow this link**
https://github.com/therandomspoon/hechillin/blob/main/script.js

The original parameters of the JavaScript was set to pause at 8:15 and 8:16 however it did not go off at the allocated time. I don’t know why and i was wondering if you could help. Credit will be given on the website.
Many Thanks,
Therandomspoon

Comment: Why are there backslashes before the `>` and `<` in your comparison? Those are syntax errors. If you added them because of formatting problems, please read the help and use the formatting tools provided in the toolbar.

Comment: You seem to be looking to see if it's 8:15 in the morning at the moment you do this. Was that really what you meant to do? Also, beware of using leading zeros on number literals; [more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Bad_octal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will once the video is played check every interval if the video is still playing, then if the current time is past 5 seconds it will pause the video for 3 seconds. It also has to clean itself up afterwards with the `removeEventListener` and `clearInterval`.

```js
const video = document.getElementById("video")
const isVideoPlaying = mediaElement => !!(mediaElement.currentTime > 0 && !mediaElement.paused && !mediaElement.ended && mediaElement.readyState > 2);

const videoPlayPauseEventCallBack = (event) => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (isVideoPlaying(event.target)){
      console.log(event.target.currentTime)
      if (event.target.currentTime >= 5){
        event.target.removeEventListener("playing", videoPlayPauseEventCallBack)
        clearInterval(interval)
        event.target.pause()
        setTimeout(() => {
          event.target.play()
        }, 3000)
      }
    }
  })
}

video.addEventListener("playing", videoPlayPauseEventCallBack)
```